# 'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, viewmodel, ienumerable

I'm trying to list all my Users, but I'm getting the following error:

> 'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for 'UsersVm' and no extension method 'UserVm' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found

My Code is as follow:

**Model:**

```
public class UserEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Username { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class UsersIndex
    {
        public IEnumerable<UserEntity> UsersVm { get; set; }
    }
```

**View** (I get the error here at '`.UsersVm`')

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBlog.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.UsersIndex>

<h1>Admin Users</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var user in Model.UsersVm)
    {
        <li>@user.Username</li>
    }
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        MyBlogEntities db = new MyBlogEntities();

        // GET: Admin/Users
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var users = db.Users.ToList();
            return View(users);
        }
    }
```

**MyBlogEntities (DbContext)**

```
public class MyBlogEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You probably meant `@foreach (var user in Model.SelectMany(x => x.UsersVm))`

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        @foreach (var userVm in user.UsersVm)
        {
            <li>@userVm.Username</li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Class UsersIndex is not needed, and then the View becomes this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBlog.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.UserEntity>

<h1>Admin Users</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <li>@user.Username</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare a class `UsersIndex` but you do not seem to use it. The controller needs to instantiate and pass a `UsersIndex` value to the view, and the view's `@model` needs to accept a `UsersIndex` rather than an `IEnumerable<UsersIndex>`

Answer (score 0):

Your view model contains an IEnumerable. The Model used in your view is an IEnumerable of view models. So essentially you have collections nested within a collection. I assume that you only want a single collection? In which case you either do not need the view model at all, or you should change the model used in your view to `@model MyBlog.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.UserEntity`.

If the collections nested within a collection is on purpose, then I would suggest that you place everything inside the view model and still have `@model MyBlog.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.UserEntity` in your view.